# BouncyCastle signature value does not match with dotNET signature value

Tags: java, .net, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle

I have a problem with the `"SHA1withRSA"` signature using Bouncy Castle on Android: Bouncy Castle signature value does not match with .NET signature value.

I tried to use many algorithms like `"SHA1withRSA"`, `"SHA1withRSAAndMGF1"` or `"SHA1withRSA/ISO9796-2"` with no satisfactory results.

If I use the same message, same algorithm and the same private key, the result must be identical in .NET and Bouncy Castle... shouldn't it? 
Whats wrong in my code???

Getting the private key:

```
... 
ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); 
... 
key = ks.getKey(alias, senha.toCharArray()); 
if (key instanceof PrivateKey) { 
    privateKey = (PrivateKey) key; 
}
```

Signature method:

```
public String signer(String txt, String alg) throws Exception { 
    Signature signer = Signature.getInstance(alg, new BouncyCastleProvider()); 
    signer.initSign(privateKey); 
    signer.update(txt.getBytes("UTF-8")); 
    return Base64.encodeToString(signer.sign(), Base64.NO_WRAP); 
}
```

My app must use XMLDSIG protocol to send XML to a government's web service.

Comment: RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_55 signatures are deterministic, RSASSA-PSS signatures are randomized.

Comment: @owlstead You mixed up OAEP (used for encryption) and PSS (used for signing)

Comment: Please show us (at least) the algorithm used in the .NET code, or the source code which creates the class containing the cryptographic algorithm.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You specified 1_55 signatures :)

Answer (score 3):

Value being signed can have some random padding data (is your signature is always the same on one side?). You should generate signature on one side and try to verify on the other.

This is especially the case for the following algorithms:

```
"SHA1WITHRSAANDMGF1"
"SHA224WITHRSAANDMGF1"
"SHA256WITHRSAANDMGF1"
"SHA384WITHRSAANDMGF1"
"SHA512WITHRSAANDMGF1"
```

Install the Bouncy Castle provider and see if the signature can be verified with the public key.